# regarding extracting substrings from existing strings by following a given pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a set of strings that show the following pattern:

```
AB01234-01B
BC4567-02C
```

I want to extract the substring from these strings by only keeping the middle digit numbers.

For instance, for the first one, I only need `1234`, and remove  `AB0` and `-01B`

For the second one, I only need 4567. How to achieve this objective in perl

Comment: In `AB0`, `0` is a digit. Is this a typo, or do you have some rule that defines that behaviour? E.g. "strip leading zeroes"?

Comment: Hi, TLP, 0 is a digit, and it has to be removed.

Comment: @user288609 I did not ask you to verify what I just said, I asked you to elaborate on the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work for you:

```
's/^[a-z0]+(\d+).*$/\1/i'
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       - start of the text
[a-z0]+ - match 1 or more of a-z alphabets or number 0
\d+     - match 1 or more decimal number
(\d+)   - group these numbers to be back referenced later
.*      - match 0 or more any characters
$       - end of text
\1      - replace with back reference # 1 which is what we have in brackets (\d+)
/i      - ignore case
```

So in the string `AB01234-01B` it groups 1234 together using (\d+) after matching AB0 and replaces whole string with `1234`.

Comment: I tried  echo "AB01234-01B" | perl -nle 's/^[a-z0]+(\d+).*$/\1/i'
but it did not work

Comment: `echo "AB01234-01B" | perl -pe 's/^[a-z0]+(\d+).*$/\1/i'` gives `1234` Don't use `-nle` use `-pe` option.

Comment: aunbhava, thanks fo rthe answer, it really solves my problem. One more question, I can understand how most of this regex work, but how to understand the part of *$/\1/i

Comment: Oh np, I will add some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "AB01234-01B\nBC4567-02C"|perl -nle 'm{0*(\d+)} and print $1'
1234
4567
```

Comment: Thanks,but how to remove 0 from 01234?

Comment: One way to remove the leading zero is to match it zero or more times before the capture group.  I amended my response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the rule is to remove leading zeroes only, the simplest way is to let perl convert the string to a number, as `"0123"` will become `123`.

```
while(<DATA>) {
    say 0+$_ for /(\d+)/;
}

__DATA__
AB01234-01B
BC4567-02C
```

Or as a sub:

```
sub extract {
    return 0+$1 if ($_[0] =~ /(\d+)/);
}
```